# What does " :: " do and how do you use " :: " in powershell scripts?

Tags: powershell, variables, operators

Is it the equivalent of objectName.method or attribute in C#? An example or 2 would be helpful to learn exactly how to use this syntax of ::

Comment: Very simple: `[type]::staticmember`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [about_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.3#static-member-operator-) help topic:

```
:: Static member operator
    Calls the static properties operator and methods of a .NET
    Framework class. To find the static properties and methods of an
    object, use the Static parameter of the Get-Member cmdlet.
   
    [datetime]::now
```

That's basically it.

The static member operator takes a type literal on the left hand side, and allows access to that type's static members (methods and properties alike):

```bash
# The PowerShell class can only be instantiated through a static method called Create()
$psInstance = [powershell]::Create()
```

You can also use it on a variable containing a type:

```bash
$dt = [datetime]
$UtcTimestamp = $dt::UtcNow
```

Comment: Thank you-:: is basically a way to reference commands then. Like object.getObjectName()

Comment: @KingofNES *only* **static** methods - not instance methods.

Comment: You can apply `::` to any value, not only `[Type]` value: `$now = Get-Date; $now::UtcNow`.

Comment: @PetSerAl pretty sure that doesn't work pre-version 5.0 (can't test right now)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Just tested, yes it does not work in v4.